# Real Time Data - Angular2 App

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I want to make an app in angular2 which can have a parent client who can send real time data to it's children clients.I will just type and send data in form of numbers and strings which should be displayed to child clients in real time.I just want to know is there any special provision in angular2 for this ?
I'm a beginner so please provide me some rough insight on this.

Comment: Are you talking about realtime data from a server somewhere? Or just the ability to have data passed from parent components down the component tree on the client side?

Comment: Initially i want to simply pass data from parent components down the component tree.Will get data from server at a later stage.

Comment: Angular2 provies the `@Input` and `@Output` annotations for this purpose. There are countless examples online for using them

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  how can that be achieved using an api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**parent.component.html**

```
<sonComponent [sonData]="parentData"></sonComponent>
```

**son.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'sonComponent',
    "<div> {{sonData}} </div>"
})
@Injectable()
export class sonComponent{
    @Input()sonData;
    constructor( 
    ) { 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Does it help? Is this what you are looking for?